# What do the entries of the Riemann curvature tensor exactly represent? E.g. $R_{231}$

Tags: tensors, curvature

I understand that the Riemann curvature tensor is a rank-4 tensor, in other words a 4x4x4 cube of 64 numbers (which can be reduced because of symmetries etc.)

The tensor represents the tidal force that a rigid body is experiencing when moving a long the shortest path between two points.

It also represents how much a vector is changed after parallel transporting.

[image]

I am really curious what exactly the $R_{231}$ entry represents. I am looking it up but I only get lost in christoffel symbols and very long derivations. What exactly does that entry mean specifically? I know it is very complicated stuff, but the metric tensor is basically a list of numbers that represent the distance you make when you put a small step in a certain direction and the stress-energy tensor is just a list of numbers representing flow across an area. I very much hope there is a way to understanding the Riemann curvature tensor (and the derived Ricci tensor etc).

My guess is that $R_{231}$ represents the difference between a vector transported in the $3$? direction and then the $1$? direction that is pointed in the $2$? direction? How can you get the tidal force from this? Or how is it related to the volume of something that gets transported?

Comment: The Riemann tensor has *four*, not three, indices.

Comment: Have a look at Visual Differential Geometry by T needham. It is gives one of the most beautiful simple explanation of it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will look into it.. @K.defaoite well that shows how much I don't understand it, could you help me with that?

Comment: The Riemann tensor measures how much covariant derivatives commute with each other.

Comment: @Buraian that is a beautiful book thank you for you suggestion.

Comment: @K.defaoite could you explain it a bit more? How doe the indices relate to the derivatives and directions etetera? That is the nature of my question